# inline locally abstract types in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

Do I have to write a function to locally bind a type ?

Using an auxiliary function works, but trying to do so as part of a type decoration of a term during destructuring does not seem to work.

```ml
type ('a, 'b) eq
type 'a repr = TpFun : ('a, 'x -> 'y) eq   -> 'a repr

let rewrite1 (type x y b f) (fxy : (f, x -> y) eq) : (f, x -> b) eq =
  failwith ""

let eqp : type a b. a repr -> (a, b) eq = function
  | TpFun (fxy) ->
      let x = rewrite1 fxy in
      _

let eqpFAIL : type a b. a repr -> (a, b) eq = function
  | TpFun ((fxy : type x y. (a, x -> y) eq) ) ->
      let x = failwith "" in
      _
```

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: does this one works in your version of ocaml ? I have "Syntax error after unclosed (, expecting `_'ocamllsp" where the pattern match happens. There is no binding the "locally bound" x and y parameters

Comment: It's not syntactically valid. I get `wildcard "_" not expected.`

Comment: I guess ocamlLSP is wired differently. I'll use `assert false` in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in https://ocaml.org/manual/gadts-tutorial.html#s%3Aexplicit-existential-name, the correct syntax for binding existential type in pattern is

```ml
let eqp : type a b. a repr -> (a, b) eq = function
  | TpFun (type x y) (fxy :(a, x -> y) eq) ->
      assert false
```

Beware also that you probably don't want to use an abstract type for `eq` since the type checker cannot infer any property on an abstract types that might have been defined as an abbreviation!

```ml
type ('a, 'b) eq = int
```

I am generally advising to use a type definition with an existing name:

```ml
type ('a,'b) eq = Eq
```

because that construction guarantees injectivity with respect to the type constructor parameters and allow the type checker to infer some type inequalities.

Comment: Ok.... I only looked at https://ocaml.org/manual/locallyabstract.html and missed that .. my bad. thank you.